# what is ment by manipulate the representation of web resources

Tags: rest

I just came across  this sentence **primary purpose of the service is to manipulate representations of Web resources**.So I just wanted to know what it actually means, does it in some way manipulate the URL? 
If yes then can anyone give an example of an URL before and after the manipulation?

Comment: What's the context? Where did you read this?

Comment: *I just red "choose the color red, it's best in this case", can you explain to me why?* Please tell us at least where you took this from.

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of a RESTful service.  The URI represents a specific resource on the server (e.g., http://server/users/5).  GET, PUT, POST and DELETE operations are then used to manipulate this resource.  Representations are the DTO's that are sent in the request/response.